# bash passing arguments invalid (adb)

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, adb

sorry for my English.
I write bash-file, that uses variable: `shared_var=/system/xbin`

**My script-file:**

```
exec="./adb shell chmod 644 $shared_var/$2"
echo $exec
$exec
```

**Let's run this script:**

```
>bash gapp.sh misc su
./adb shell chmod 644 /system/xbin/su
: No such file or directory n/su
```

**Let's run string "./adb shell chmod 644 /system/xbin/su" without script:**

```
> ./adb shell chmod 644 /system/xbin/su
(No output, OK)
```

I have few questions:

1. Why are script and direct input in terminal have different results?
2. Why instead of "No such file or directory /system/xbin/su" adb returns "No soch file or directoryn/su" (adb result looks distorted)
3. What is solution of my problem?

Comment: Also, please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does it work, if your shell script only has

```
echo ./adb shell chmod 644 $shared_var/$2
./adb shell chmod 644 $shared_var/$2
```

ie, not assigning it to another variable, and no quoted strings

Also, if you are editing the file in Windows, make sure you save the file with `Unix` linefeeds.

Comment: It gives same result:
echo ./adb shell chmod 644 $shared_var/$2
gives 
./adb shell chmod 644 /system/xbin/su

./adb shell chmod 644 $shared_var/$2
returns
: No such file or directoryn/su

But 
./adb shell chmod 644 /system/xbin/su
executes successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, how to do a new line in this comments :(

Comment: Ohhh!
The reason of this were windows-like end-of-lines.
I changed it for UNIX-style in gedit, and now all is working fine.
Sorry :(

Comment: Ah, yes, when you create scripts in Windows, you need to convert the file to Unix linefeeds or else it will not run correctly in unix.  (I work in Linux mostly, but I've run into this a number of times as well)